# My first loop is not working

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I'm new in coding, and can't understand why my code not working?
Any syntax error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int height;
int row;
int space;
int hash;

int main(void)
{
    // ask user for input  
    do
    {
        printf("height: ");
        height = GetInt();
    }  
    while (height < 0 || height > 23);

    // make pyramid

    for (row = 1; row >= height; row++)
    {
        for (space = (height - row); space > 0; space--)
        {
            printf("8 ");
        }

        for (hash = 1; hash >= (row+1); hash++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program asks Height, then got it and exits. (Loop is not working).

Comment: You should not ask us if there are syntax errors. Your compiler tells you if there are any.
Take care about the `;` at the end of your while loop. This loop will not do much...
Where does the last `}` belong to?
And regarding your question in general: What do you expect, what does happen?

Comment: Compiler demands this ` ;`

Comment: The compiler wants a valid expression which might be a block or a statement. You provide an empty statement.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets examine the beginning of your code:

```
while (height < 0 || height > 23);
```

Here you are saying that the height should be either lower than zero or higher than 23. Can your pyramid have a negative height? It would be better just switch to:

```
while(height< 23)
```

Also, you are using `;` after the while. While syntax is like this:

```
while(condition) 
{
     do something;
}
```

I tried running your code and it seems like that you are getting the logic wrong. For instance, inside the `while`, you don't modify the condition of the loop, making it an infinite loop. Just adjust the `for` correctly and it will work.

EDIT - Since you are using `Do/While` the syntax is this:

```
do
{
   something;
}
while(condition);
```

The action that you want to be performed in loop needs to be inside the `do` brackets.

Comment: I assume the while loop should rather be an if: `if (height > 0 && height < 23);`
Also the loop should get a different condition: `for (row = 1; row <= height; row++)`

Otherwise the loop will not do much if height is not 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

(**edit**: this answer is out of context because OP edited their post. By  the time I answered, there was no `do { } while` statement)

In addition to what others have said about syntax error and your program's logic, I'd like to advise you to be careful about semicolons at the wrong places. When you write something like this:

```
while (height < 0 || height > 23);
```

...you are making your program loop without doing anything as long as the conditions are true. The `;` makes the body of your while loop empty.

This can also happen with other constructs. It's very common to see people complain in forums that they spent a whole night tracking a bug only to find out it was a semicolon at the wrong place.

My tip to you is: **always** use braces. Even when they don't seem necessary.